# Changing a function to return an array instead of a string. Too difficult?

Tags: php

I have a PHP function like this:

```
function count_nutrient_value($input){
 // some difficult operations here
 return $output; // this is a string
}
```

Which I'm using like this (example):

```
$print .= 'This nutrient is giving you '.count_nutrient_value(40).' percent.';
```

The problem now is that from the function, I need to return another value - an info whether the number is rising or falling. So I change the function:

```
function count_nutrient_value_new($input){
 // some difficult operations here
 return array($output,$status); // this is an array, obviously
}
```

But now I cannot use the function so easily, as I cannot do this anymore:

```
$print .= 'This nutrient is giving you '.count_nutrient_value_new(40).' percent.';
```

But instead, I need to expand it to more lines, like this:

```
$return = count_nutrient_value_new(40);
$print .= 'This nutrient is giving you '.$return[0].' percent.';
```

Is there a solution to this situation? This would be:

A) Not return an array from the function (but solve the problem some other way)
B) Return an array and find an easier way of using the function in the code
C) Other?

Comment: A function should only really be responsible for one thing. Break it up into two functions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make two functions for each purpose, and call one from the other.

```
function count_nutrient_value_string( $input ){
    $array = count_nutrient_value_array( $input );
    return $array[ 0 ];
}

function count_nutrient_value_array( $input ){
     // some difficult operations here
     return array( $output, $status ); 
}

$print .= 'This nutrient is giving you '.count_nutrient_value_string(40).' percent.';
```

(The function names should be better than `_string` and `_array` depending on what they actually do.)

Comment: Wow, this is a great idea!

Comment: @RichardRodriguez Make sure too that you don't duplicate your code between the two functions. If there's common code, call one function from the other, or have them both call a third function. This answer already does that, but without mentioning it, and I wanted to emphasize it a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid changing the signature of a function since it may break some code. Instead, I'd rather add and call a new function.

Anyway, if I had to change the function in the way you describe here, I'd use an utilisty class instead of an array.

- The class would have two attributes : $count and $status, whether yuo make them public or not is a matter of convenience. In your case, I guess public attibutes are fine.
- The class could also implement the __toString() method in order to maintain compatibility whith the old code.

Something like :

```
class nutrientResults {

    public $status = SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE;
    public $count = 0;

    public function __construct($count, $st = SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE) {
         $this->count = $count;
         $this->status = $st;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->count;
    }

}
```

Then :

```
function count_nutrient_value($input){
    // some difficult operations here
    return new nutrientResults($count, $status);
}

$print .= 'This nutrient is giving you '.count_nutrient_value(40).' percent.';
// as usual..., so backwards compatibility maintained
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use output parameters.

```
function count_nutrient_value($input, &$out1, &$out2){
 // some difficult operations here
 $out1 = $output[0];
 $out2 = $output[1];
 return $output[0]; // return the same
}

$print .= 'This nutrient is giving you '.count_nutrient_value(40, $o1, $o2).' percent.';
// Do other things with $o1 and $o2.
```

In php 5 you can also use optional parameters:

```
function count_nutrient_value($input, &$out1 = '', &$out2 = ''){
 // some difficult operations here
 $out1 = $output[0];
 $out2 = $output[1];
 return $output[0]; // return the same
}

// Call without out parameters
$print .= 'This nutrient is giving you '.count_nutrient_value(40).' percent.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the function into a small class with `$output` and $status as properties:

```
class count_nutrient_value() {
public $output;
public $status;
function __construct($input) {
   // Do complicate stuff here
   $this->output = $output_result;
   $this->status = $status_result;
}
}
```

Then you can do

```
$nutrient = new count_nutrient_value($input);
$print .= 'This nutrient is giving you '.$nutrient->output.' percent.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Spliting up the functions in a data source and some accessors/transformers is probably the right choice.
In case you're using all (or most) of the information of the array/object returned by your data source anyway it would still probably better to store/cahche it once instead of recreating each time your accessor function is called.
And as a simple replacement for what you've got right now take a look at the **v**printf function family. Instead of using an elipsis (`printf($format, ...)` e.g. `printf('%d %s %d', 1,'a', 3)`) they take an array of arguments: `vprintf('%d %s %d', array(1,'a', 3))` which can easily be passed from or to another function.

```
<?php
function count_nutrient_value($input) {
    return array($input*0.1, ' approved');
}

$result = vsprintf('This%2$s nutrient is giving you %1$d percent.', count_nutrient_value(40));
echo $result;
```

see http://docs.php.net/function.vsprintf

Answer (score -2):

You can return array value with example code:

```
function count_nutrient_value_new($input){
 // some difficult operations here
 return array('output' => $output, 'status' => $status); // this is an array, obviously
}
```

And then to get the value is:

```
$print .= 'This nutrient is giving you '.$return["output"].' percent.';
```

Comment: This isn't a solution to OP question... it's just returning an associative array rather than indexed.